# AMD RenderMonkey GLSG Config for Alpha Transparency

Tags: opengl, glsl, alphablending

I'm trying to use RenderMonkey to design a GLSL shader that uses Alpha transparency, and the RenderState editor doesn't use the same terms I'm used to from OpenGL. Can anyone advise on how to configure it for simple Alpha transparency?

Answer (score 5):

RenderMonkey breaks out the RGB and A of the source and dest, whereas OpenGL handles them both as one with the combinations in the GLenums like GL_SRC_ALPHA and GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA passed to glBlendFunc(). For example, GL_SRC_ALPHA sets up the source of the RGB *and* A, but it appears RenderMonkey wants to do them individually. So, once you turn on GL_BlendEnable TRUE, you just need to set:
GL_BlendDestAlpha INV_SRC_ALPHA (equivalent to the A portion of GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
GL_BlendDestRGB INV_SRC_ALPHA (equivalent to the RGB portion of GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
GL_BlendSourceAlpha SRC_ALPHA (equivalent to the RGB portion of GL_SRC_ALPHA)
GL_BlendSourceRGB SRC_ALPHA (equivalent to the RGB portion of GL_SRC_ALPHA)